# Unable to use Vim to open LaTeX files on Mac, caused by Python?

Tags: python, macos, vim, macvim

## The problem:

MacVim is failing me at opening `*.tex` files. I have nothing too fancy for this specific filetype (vimtex and vim-latex-suite, at most), yet, I cannot use MacVim to edit `*.tex` files on my MacBook Air, running latest OS X.

- If I open the `*.tex` file through a graphical interface (MacVim), the MacVim process simply quits;
- If I try to call `macvim` from the Terminal, to open such `*.tex` file, I will end up with the following **diagnostic** info:

> ```
> Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system codec
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
>
> Current thread 0x00007fff9b28c3c0 (most recent call first):
> Vim: Caught deadly signal ABRT
> Vim: Finished.
> ```

- For now, I am settled with typing my LaTeX documents through the plain `vim` interface @ the terminal.

## Failed troubleshooting attempts:

I do not have trouble using `python` and `python3` command through the Terminal (this is a Mac, after all); and I have also tried to specify the following `$PYTHONHOME` to Vim. This did not help me to restore MacVim functionality with `*.tex` files.

```
let $PYTHONHOME = "/Users/llinfeng/anaconda2/bin/python"
```

## Vim-configuration info

Also, I don't see myself doing anything fancy in the `~/.vim/ftplugin/tex.vim` file. Notably, I am reusing almost all the Vim settings across Windows, Linux and Mac machines. So far, I have been happily typing LaTeX in my Windows and Linux machine.

Please let me know if there is further diagnostics info that I can provide.

Comment: It seems like a problem of mvim. You could try to `brew upgrade python3` or `brew reinstall vim --with-python3`. Good luck! More on that [here](https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/issues/411).

Comment: @ryuichiro Fantastic reference! Let me give it a try and report back here.

Comment: @ryuichiro Updating the `python3` did help address the problem. However, how did you identify the problem: say, that I need to update Python 2 instead of Python 3? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

With all credits attributed to @ryuichiro (see comments), running the following command through Terminal helped solve the problem:

```
brew upgrade python3
```

I can now type LaTeX documents as usual; but, I have no idea why `python3` should be "upgraded" to get MacVim back alive. [Will add explanation if I am briefed with one.]